# Math Probability with C# - How to get the enumerated value of 3 different characters at a certain try

Tags: c#, math, probability

Hi I have asked this question yesterday and was closed of being not understood, so I'll try to be more specific as I can this time. So here's the situation.

**1.** I have 3 characters: A, B, C in a character array like the following :

```
char[] characters = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
```

**2.** when enumerating all possible matches of these 3 characters I get for example the following:

```
Text    = A
tries   = 1
indexes = characters[0] 
------------
Text    = B
tries   = 2
indexes = characters[1] 
------------
Text    = C
tries   = 3
indexes = characters[2] 
------------
Text    = AA
tries   = 4
indexes = characters[0] characters[0] 
------------
Text    = AB
tries   = 5
indexes = characters[0] characters[1] 
------------
Text    = AC
tries   = 6
indexes = characters[0] characters[2] 
------------
Text    = BA
tries   = 7
indexes = characters[1] characters[0] 
------------
Text    = BB
tries   = 8
indexes = characters[1] characters[1] 
------------
Text    = BC
tries   = 9
indexes = characters[1] characters[2] 
------------
Text    = CA
tries   = 10
indexes = characters[2] characters[0] 
------------
Text    = CB
tries   = 11
indexes = characters[2] characters[1] 
------------
Text    = CC
tries   = 12
indexes = characters[2] characters[2]
```

**3.** Now given the number of certain try, can we get the number of indexes at this specific try? Meaning for example at the try number 10 at this try the Text was CA (as shown above) because the indexes was characters[2] & characters[0], So is there a Math equation to know these indexes numbers having the number of try?

Thank you

Comment: I really don't understand what real world problem this is trying to solve. It reads like homework (and I don't see why you tagged it with [tag:probability] either. Can you explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) already?

Comment: Why does `AA` result in 4 tries? Wouldn't it result in 2 tries?

Comment: @JoelRondeau - From the examples, I think "tries" means the # of the example (i.e. AA is option #4)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Is this homework? Without giving the answer away, do you know what a recurrence relation is? Another possibility is to create a Dictionary that has 'A' through 'CC' as its key and try 1 through 12 as its value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can we get the number of indexes at this specific try

For any given number of letters, you are just counting numbers in base-3.  So simply convert from decimal to base-3, and back again.

To determine how many possibilities there are for lesser string-lengths:  there are 3^n different possible strings of length `n` that use 3 letters.

Comment: @Mohamed Tarek: It's easier to see if you start your array of characters at position 1 instead of 0. Then a conversion of n tries in base 10 to base 3 will yield the indices directly.

Comment: @BlueRaja Using your idea I was able after some alteration to get the exact value to convert it correctly. Many thanks.

Comment: @JisBen Also your comment has helped me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `try` is less than 4:

```
characters[try-1]
```

Otherwise:

```
characters[(try-4)/3], characters[(try-4)%3]
```

where `%` is the modulus operator and `/` is integer division

So for `try == 10` you get:

```
characters[2], characters[1]
```

*Note*: as your try values start from 1 and the indices start from 0, we need a -1 right from the start

*Note*: due to the way the modulus operation works, the second index could have also been written as `(try-1)%3`

Comment: Thanks for your response but what does the the comma in the second equation stand for?

Comment: @MohamedTarek - No specific meaning, just separating the two values